# How to implement multi-tenant JWT Authentication with different AWS Cognito UserPools per tenant with .Net Core

Tags: authentication, .net-core, jwt, amazon-cognito, multi-tenant

I have a diifferent AWS Cognito UserPool per Tenant, but I need to be able to validate the token depending on the tenant-specific request.

I'm aware that there is currently no support for this in .Net Core. Can anyone advise a way to handle this? Can you dynamically set the JWT Bearer once the application is running?

To get it working, I've tried to add multiple JWTBearers in the Startup.cs, but I encounter the error: `InvalidOperationException: Scheme already exists: Bearer`.

```
 services.AddAuthentication(o =>
            {
                o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.SaveToken = true;
                cfg.TokenValidationParameters = <TENANT_1_CONFIG>.TokenValidationParameters();
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.SaveToken = true;
                cfg.TokenValidationParameters = <TENANT_2_CONFIG>.TokenValidationParameters();
            });
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to set this config once the application is running, depending on the request.